# how to remove specific image from $_FILE[]?

Tags: php

I have this piece of PHP code by which I want to remove the file which not meets this below condition from file array

```
$file_name=$_FILES["files"]["name"];
$file_tmp=$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"];
$data='';
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($file_tmp);$i++)
{
    $filesize=getimagesize($file_tmp[$i]);
    $width=$filesize[0];
    $height=$filesize[1];
    if ($width < "854" ||  $height < "1280") 
    {
        echo "remove file from $_FILE[]";    
    } else {
        $_FILE[]
    }
}
```

Comment: UNSET($file_name);

Comment: @siddhartha I tried but still file name showing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try its

```
if ($width < "854" ||  $height < "1280") 
    {
        @unlink($file_tmp);
        echo "remove file from $file_name";    
    } else {
        echo $file_name;
    }
```

Comment: You should only `@unlink($file_tmp);` - `$_FILES[...]["name"];` is the name of the file at the client - the code above allows the user to delete arbitrary files on the server!